# Python Dash Plotly: dcc.Upload gives error POST 500 after deployment

Tags: python, file-upload, plotly-dash, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

I used dcc.upload() to handle the file upload. The file can be uploaded and read locally on the localhost.
But after the deployment, I received POST 500 internal server error. And the message received is:
`{message: "Callback error updating output-data-upload.children", html: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final/…ded or there is an error in the application.</p>\n"}`
The code related to this error message has been attached below as a screenshot, where `output-data-upload` is the id of a html.Div() component.
And the `upload-data` is the id of the dcc.Upload() component.
In the `parse_contents()`, I'm trying to filter for xls or xlsx files only. in the `update_output()`, I'm trying to display the name of the uploaded file.

I've looked up the 500 error code and have tried to change some permission settings but nothing really worked out.\

I really appreciate the help!

[code related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IcKO.png)

Comment: The 500 error code indicates that a server error occurred. Please post the server log file.

Comment: MacBook-Pro aciseagentd[398]: Function: loadXMLCfgFile Thread Id: 0xB951E00 File: /tmp/build/thehoff/Negasonic_MR30.610359133743/Negasonic_MR3/posture/ise/libnaccommon/ConfigData.cpp Line: 46 Level: warn :: ISEPostureCFG.xml not found, using defaults
MacBook-Pro aciseagentd[398]: Function: GetConfigData Thread Id: 0xB951E00 File: /tmp/build/thehoff/Negasonic_MR30.610359133743/Negasonic_MR3/posture/ise/libnaccommon/ConfigData.cpp Line: 217 Level: warn :: The cfg parameter for numeric value VlanDetectInterval was invalid. Using default. (XML was )
if I found the log correctly?